# Using ruby's 'case'/'when' method with || or && operators, etc

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, case, or-operator, andand

I just tried to run some code that looked like this

```
def get_proj4(srid, type=nil)
  type.downcase! if type
  case type
  when nil || "epsg"
   open("http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/#{srid}/proj4/").read
  when "esri"
   open("http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/#{srid}/proj4/").read
  end
end
```

and it didn't run properly, returning nil every time. wrapping the `nil || "epsg"` in parentheses didn't work either

It turns out ruby wouldn't allow me to use the `||` operator in this

Now I assume ruby takes the case/when method and ultimately breaks it down into a group of conditionals looking something like

```
x = type
  if x == (nil || "epsg")
    y = ...runs code...
  elsif x == "esri"
    y = ...
  end
x = nil
y
```

but obviously it does not. What's going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression is evaluated *first* so `when nil || "espg"` is equivalent to `when "espg"`<sup>1</sup> - it will never match `nil`.

To match either-or, separate the options with a comma:

```
case type
when nil, "espg" ..
when "esri" ..
```

Or, alternatively, perhaps normalize the value:

```
case (type || "espg")
when "espg" ..
when "esri" ..
```

Or use the other form that resembles an if-else:

```
case
when type.nil? || type == "espg" ..
when type == "esri" ..
```

Or some combination of everything :)

---

<sup>1</sup> This is also the same reason why the example `if` is suspect. It should probably be written like:

```
if type.nil? || type == "espg"
```

Comment: ahh `x == nil || "epsg"` **does** match nil **but**, as it the line continues to evaluate, it has to move on from that match because of the nature of the || operator i.e. `(nil || false) => next`. gotcha, and then it doesn't match "epsg", and its on to the next one...(?) that kind of makes sense

Comment: @boulder_ruby If it written like that, then yes - but it will always be a truthy expression (as `anything || "espg"` is truthy) so it should never match any alternative branch.

Comment: nil isn't `anything`. what's anything? ruby doesn't have an object for that!!! except for `Object`, of course...erm.....

Comment: But don't try to match nil, got it. That's what false is for (?)

Comment: @boulder_ruby I meant `anything` to mean it doesn't matter what the `x == nil` expression evaluates to - if it evaluates to a truthy value that will be the reuslt, but if it evaluates to a falsey value (namely, false) then "espg" (a truthy value) will result. `a || b` is short-circuiting, and will always evaluate to a truthy-value if either expression a *or* b evaluates truthy; otherwise it will result in false.